# WCF Client to WSE 3.0 service Exception: CWWSS7310E: XML encryption information[.....]

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, wse3.0

I have never worked with soap services before, so I might have done something wrong. I have generated a service client reference for the service through it's wsdl with "Svcutil".

I have followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-wcf-client-to-interoperate-with-wse3-0-services and set up the custom binding.
After that I a client from the reference and supply a new binding that is using WseSecurityAssertion.MutualCertificate10 and the service endpoint address.

I then add a certificate and add theese credentails to the service client:

```
clientProxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(string.Concat(xxx, yyy), GetCertificatePassword(xxx), PersistKeySet);
            clientProxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(xxx, "", PersistKeySet);
            clientProxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = ChainTrust;
            clientProxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = NoCheck;
```

This is code that have worked before (but before using wcf and "Svcutil") and I have mostly copied it, but refactored it a bit.

When I call the Web Service I get this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'CWWSS5511E: An exception occurred during the decryption of a message. The exception is CWWSS7310E: XML encryption information exists in the security header, however an inbound XML encryption configuration is not present.'
```

I understand that I encrypt something that I shouldn't and when I compare the request I sent with the old code to the request I send now I can see that this is added in the securityheader:

```
<e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

And some info about the key.

I'm wondering what it is I do wrong that the code didn't do before. I can't find any config files so I don't think it's some configuration I have missed. Where might this encryption be set? Is it inside the binding or is it where I set clientCredentials?

Comment: So this is old code?  What changes did you make?  Did you change versions of Net?  Are you now using Windows 10?  I haven't seen this error before but have worked with a lot of postings with Certificates.  It worked before using wcf and Svutil which helps.  See if it still works with wcf and SVutil?  If it still works then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request in working with non working.  There may be something different in the http request headers that may explain the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after alot of reading and comparing I finaly figured out that I did not set 
ProtectionLevel to System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign in the new generation of the service reference file. this was probably hardcoded there in the old ones instead of using a config file to set the ProtectionLevel. 
This is what caused the service on the service side to not understand how to decrypt it correctly.